# How do I get an object stored in a variable, from a foreach loop, to be passed into a method?

Tags: c#, methods, console-application

I cannot get my item `KartItem` to be passed into the parameter. I tried to debug and it shows the data in the item, but then when I try to pass it into the  `Deals.BuyOneGetOneFree(item)` it doesn't work.

Piece of code from main

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Item");
var inputItem = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter Pounds");
int inputPound = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter Price");
double inputCost = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
kart.PutItemInKart(inputItem, inputPound, inputCost);
Console.WriteLine("your item in the kart");
foreach (var item in kart.GetKart())
{
    Deals.BuyOneGetOneFree(item); <--- Here
    Console.WriteLine(item.Item);          
}
```

The method I need item to be passed into

```
public static string BuyOneGetOneFree(KartItem inKart)
{  
    if (inKart.Item == "Lettuce" || inKart.Item == "Pespsi" || inKart.Item == "Water")
    {
        double newCost = inKart.Cost * 2;
        return "Your get one buy one credit applied today ! " + newCost.ToString();
    }
    return "There is no discount for your item at this time";
}
```

kart item class:

```
public class KartItem
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public int Pound { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public KartItem(string item, int pound, double cost)
    {
        Item = item;
        Pound = pound;
        Cost = cost;
    }
    public KartItem()
    {

    }
}

private List<KartItem> kart = new List<KartItem>();


public List<KartItem> PutItemInKart(string input = null, int inputNumber = 0, double inputPrice = 0)
{

        kart.Add(new KartItem()
        {
            Item = input,
            Pound = inputNumber,
            Cost = inputPrice
        });;

    return kart;
}

public List<KartItem> GetKart()  
{
    return kart;
}
```

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" is not a technically description of a problem. its only a desired behavior that is not happening (which you haven't told us), even if you did its not the correct way to ask a question as its too broad. You need to be specific about not working, and do some due diligence about where the code gets to, what state its in at these points with the debugger, what errors are happening, or what you expect to happen, and what actually does happen instead ect

Comment: Did you mean item is empty when you pass it to `BuyOneGetOneFree ` method?

Comment: When I pass it to BuyOneGetOneFree  method  it does nothing. When I put in a breakpoint, it shows the data is in the variable, Item Pound and Cost.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? It doesn't look like you are doing anything with the return value or the newCost variable in your `BuyOneGetOneFree` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to seen the message resulting from the `BuyOneGetOneFree` method, you can do this.

```
foreach (var item in kart.GetKart())
{
    var message = Deals.BuyOneGetOneFree(item); // <--- Here
    Console.WriteLine(message); // show return message
    Console.WriteLine(item.Item);          
}
```

In addition, if you are want to also update the `Cost`, you need to update the item's cost property

```
public static string BuyOneGetOneFree(KartItem inKart)
{  
    if (inKart.Item == "Lettuce" || inKart.Item == "Pespsi" || inKart.Item == "Water")
    {
        double newCost = inKart.Cost * 2;
        inKart.Cost = newCost;
        return "Your get one buy one credit applied today ! " + newCost.ToString();
    }
    return "There is no discount for your item at this time";
}
```